# Can't delete the old agent Apple ID from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode6.1, apple-id

I have a problem regarding to adding Apple ID to Xcode. So far I have been using an office Apple ID as my Xcode Apple ID. Now they invited me to join as a developer. so using my own Apple ID I can access the provisioning profiles and apps in old account. And now I want to add my own apple id to the xcode and delete that old office Apple id. But I cant delete the old apple id from the xcode. When I archive the project and when try to save the .ipa file, it says cant access the account. That means they have changed the password of old account.

I have already added my private apple id to Xcode but it shows as Admin. The old Apple id shows as Agent. How can I archive my project using my new Apple ID. Please help me

Comment: Hi, first a few questions...1) are you on Yosemite, and 2) are you trying to delete the Apple ID from your keychain?

Comment: Also, is your code signed with your old Apple ID? And, if so, I would assume that your options for provisioning profile selection are limited to the ones that correspond to that ID.

Comment: yes im on Yosemite. code signed with old Apple ID but now I cant access it, they have already changed that password.

Comment: I didnt try to delete it from the keychain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is still downloaded after you delete it from your keychain (which might not be happening anymore if Apple has fixed that issue), then there is one (last?) resort you could try, before calling Apple. I would try to request a certificate, using the Certificate Assistant in your Keychain Access application. In case you aren't familiar, the Certificate Assistant is under the Keychain Access menu. The steps are pretty straight forward.

As a different approach you could also try using the xcodebuild command on the command line. This sometimes works where xCode fails, in cases where you are having trouble with managing your IDs or adding accounts within xCode.

You need the following information:

1. the full path to the project file
2. the Scheme name for the Scheme that you use for archiving, as it appears in xCode. If you don't have a scheme set up for archiving, you need to do so for this purpose.

Then you can generate the archive:
**xcodebuild archive -project [full path in quotes] -scheme [name of scheme in quotes]**

Now that it's archived, you now need to export it. For this step, you need the following information:

1. The full path to the archive you just generated. The location for xCode Archives is in xCode preferences, under the Locations tab.
2. The full path and file name of the resulting IPA file
3. The name of the provisioning profile, as it appears in xCode, e.g. the name you gave it when you set it up in the Developer Portal.

Then you can do the export:
**xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath [full path in quotes] -exportPath [full path in quotes, without the file extension] -exportFormat [usually ipa, no need for quotes] -exportProvisioningProfile [profile name, as it appears in xCode, in quotes]**

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: that old Apple ID not display in keychain access. why isthat

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but it has fixed many of my problems--did you restart xCode? Sometimes it doesn't do a good job of refreshing it's cache of keychains, while it is open. Cleaning the project (Shift-Cmd-K) does wonders sometimes also. If that doesn't help, then one thing you could try is the command-line approach. I'll post it in my answer, since it is a little verbose.

Comment: Thank you so much. waiting for that option too

Comment: Thank you so much bro,, the method that worked for me is quitting Xcode so many times. Just now before I tried ur second option I again tried to quit it and re-open. It worked. Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to keychain
2. Set all objects
3. Find your ID
4. Remove it
5. Go to `xcode -> preference -> account`
6. Now you can remove it