# Specify exportSigningIdentity on command-line with xcodebuild?

Tags: ios, command-line, archive, xcodebuild

I know it is possible to specify a provisioning profile when calling the xcodebuild command, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27916176/1231948).

However, I would like to also specify the code signing, via the exportSigningIdentity parameter. I've tried countless permutations with various parameters, and formats for this parameter, with no luck--I keep getting errors. I'm not even sure if that supplying all the required parameters.

I'm leaving out the scheme parameter, since it would conflict with the code signing specification. Unfortunately, the documentation on this is very sparse.

Thank for your help!